# DirectX: Cannot translate a rectangle

Tags: c++, directx, translation

I have been following this tutorial of DirectX http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-4-5. I have just started DirectX with C++. I have drawn two rectangles on the screen but cannot translate them.Th rectangles have different position on screen and are stored in Array **OurVertices**. I have been reading from the tutorial and it says that you first have to apply world transformation to translate it in 3d but I dont want to get into 3d because I have two simple 2d rectangles. How you move simple 2d rectangles in DirectX C++. If I apply World Transformation using the tutorial I dont know why my camera position is tilted.  My code is given below:

```
CUSTOMVERTEX OurVertices[] =
    {
    //  1
        { 0, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 0), },   //meaning x,y,z,Dword
        { 100, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 0), },
        { 0, 100, 0.0f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 0), },
        { 100, 100, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 0), },

        { 200, 200, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), },
        { 400, 200, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), },
        { 200, 400, 0.0f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), },
        { 400, 400, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), },
    };

d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(8 * sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
        0,
        CUSTOMFVF,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &v_buffer,
        NULL);
    VOID* pVoid;    // the void* we were talking about

    v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);    // locks v_buffer, the buffer we made earlier

    memcpy(pVoid, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));
    v_buffer->Unlock();    // unlock v_buffer

    d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);



void render_frame()
{ 
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    d3ddev->BeginScene();

    // select which vertex format we are using
    // select the vertex buffer to display
    d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

        // SET UP THE PIPELINE

    D3DXMATRIX matTranslate;    
    static float index = 0.0f; 
    index += 0.01f;    // an ever-increasing float value

                                                      // build a matrix to rotate the model based on the increasing float value
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslate, 0, index , 0.0f);

        // tell Direct3D about our matrix
    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matTranslate);

    D3DXMATRIX matView;    // the view transform matrix

    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
            &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f),    // the camera position
            &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),    // the look-at position
            &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));    // the up direction

    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);    // set the view transform to matView

    D3DXMATRIX matProjection;     // the projection transform matrix

    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
            D3DXToRadian(100),    // the horizontal field of view
            (FLOAT)800 / (FLOAT)600, // aspect ratio
            1.0f,    // the near view-plane
            100.0f);    // the far view-plane

    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProjection);    // set the projection

                                                                   // select the vertex buffer to display
    d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));

        // copy the vertex buffer to the back buffer
    d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);
    d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 4, 2);



    d3ddev->EndScene();

    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Is there any way to translate two rectangles?

Answer (score 1):

You are already working in 3D, when you specify the position of your vertices you have an extra z component wich is set to 0 at the moment. You can change it and see the effect on your scene.

```
    { 0, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 0), },   //meaning x,y,z,Dword
    { 100, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 0), },
    { 0, 100, 0.0f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 0), },
    { 100, 100, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 0), },

    { 200, 200, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), },
    { 400, 200, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), },
    { 200, 400, 0.0f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), },
    { 400, 400, 0.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), },
```

So now each frame you are translating your vertices by an increasing amount on the y axis.

```
static float index = 0.0f; 
index += 0.01f;    // an ever-increasing float value

// build a matrix to rotate the model based on the increasing float value
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslate, 0, index , 0.0f);
```

If you print index each frame you will see him growing and you use this value to to build a translation matrix which will be apply before view/projection.

[image]

I don't know what is the effect you want.
But all the vertices of your scene will go from bottom to top, which you can look like your camera is going down.